# what's difference between warden.authenticate? and user.valid_password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I user Devise in my rails application to authenticate user.
I find two method, "warden.authenticate?" and "user.valid_password?".
who can tell me what's difference between those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise is built on top of a library called Warden. Warden is a low-level authentication library for Rack and works as a piece of middleware in the stack. Warden provides the basis for Strategies by implementing a Base strategy from which others must inherit.

The warden method is private, so it's not accessible as an action. It needs to be made a helper method if you intend on accessing it from your views.

Hope this helps.